# Creating _.reduce from scratch

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to recreate the _.reduce method from the underscore library from scratch but I'm failing three test cases. 1. Should continue to call iterator even if the iterator returns undefined. 2. Should pass every item of the array into the iterator if a memo is passed in. 3. Should pass the second item of the array into the iterator first if a memo is not passed in. I've been looking at the docs and I thought that  iterator(accumulator, collection[1], 1, collection) would cover the third case but I guess not.

```
_.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    // TIP: To support both arrays and objects, try re-using each() here
    if (accumulator === undefined) {
      accumulator = collection[0];
      iterator(accumulator, collection[1]);
    }

    _.each(collection, function(val) {
      iterator(accumulator, val);
    }
    );
    return accumulator;
  };
```

Comment: well you don't store the result of `iterator(...)`

Comment: actually your function is nothing similar to https://underscorejs.org/#reduce (1.13.1), what do you try to implement?

Comment: well my test cases seem to disagree, I've passed 7/10 tests @appleapple

Comment: @ Ronny Fitzgerald, nothing similar to underscore.js and your (unknown) test passed is unrelated.  Also, you should make the question contains [mcve].

Comment: Why is not similar? Please dont just say negative things to put others down. The test cases I have show that I am on the right track so I dont think theyre unrelated

Comment: @ Ronny Fitzgerald, not putting you down, please visit [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: Where are your 10 test cases? What is a "memo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- In case `accumulator` is undefined, your code first calls `iterator` with `collection[1]`, but if `collection` is not an array, this will not represent the second element of the collection. For instance, the second element in `{a:1, b:2}` would be `collection.b`.
- In case `accumulator` is undefined, your code will still continue to execute `_.each` which will call `iterator` on the first element of the collection, which you wanted to avoid...
- Your code ignores the value returned by the call of `iterator`. It should capture this return value and assign it to `accumulator`
- The `iterator` should be called with a third argument: the index/key of the value.
- The `iterator` should be called with a fourth argument: the complete collection that is being iterated

Correction:

```js
_.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    _.each(collection, function(val, i) {
        if (accumulator === undefined && i === 0) accumulator = val;
        else accumulator = iterator(accumulator, val, i, collection);
    });
    return accumulator;
};

// Tests
console.log(_.reduce([1,2,3], (a, b) => a+b, 1) === 7);
console.log(_.reduce([1,2,3], (a, b) => a+b) === 6);
console.log(_.reduce({a: 1, b: 2, c:3}, (a, b, i) => a+b, 0) === 6);
console.log(_.reduce({a: 1, b: 2, c:3}, (a, b, i) => a+i, "") === "abc");
console.log(_.reduce([], (a, b) => a+b, 0) === 0);
console.log(_.reduce([], (a, b) => a+b) === undefined);
console.log(_.reduce([1,2,3], (a, b, i, all) => a + b * all[i-1]
) === 9);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd.min.js"></script>
```